# Google speech to text API in React Native question

Tags: react-native, speech-to-text, google-speech-api

I am trying to turn the following example into a code that I can use in a react app. I have tried using fetch but that hasn't worked for me yet. If there is an example out there let me know.

```
const record = require("node-record-lpcm16");

// Imports the Google Cloud client library
const speech = require("@google-cloud/speech");

// Creates a client
const client = new speech.SpeechClient();

const encoding = "LINEAR16";
const sampleRateHertz = 16000;
const languageCode = "en-US";

const request = {
  config: {
    encoding: encoding,
    sampleRateHertz: sampleRateHertz,
    languageCode: languageCode
  },
  interimResults: false 
};

// Create a recognize stream
const recognizeStream = client
  .streamingRecognize(request)
  .on("error", console.error)
  .on("data", data =>
    process.stdout.write(
      data.results[0] &&         data.results[0].alternatives[0]
    ? `Transcription: ${data.results[0].alternatives[0].transcript}\n`
    : `\n\nReached transcription time limit, press Ctrl+C\n`));
```

Comment: hie! Please add some more details! like what did the FETCH produce? i mean a glimpse of error ! so that one can see what you have tried so far and can guide you with this !

Comment: Hello, and welcome to _StackOverflow_! Its a **great** community! I think you may benefit from a [really good tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on asking questions here. Your question is pretty good for a first effort. See if that tutorial helps you make your question even better so people can help you. Good luck!